# CSS selector: first div within an id or class

Tags: css

What is the proper CSS selector to select the first div within a class or with a specific id? This seems to be much easier with parent/child elements but I haven't found anything for simple elements.

**Update: solution**

The cleanest, most compatible solution I found was .class ~ .class which selects all the latter classes that follow the former class. For example, if you wanted to remove the top border from the first element within its class you would:

```
<style>
    .dolphin {
        border-top:0;
        }
    .dolphin ~ .dolphin {
        border-top:1px solid #000;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: Your solution will only work when the elements are siblings.

Comment: You should add your solution below, rather than adding it to your question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want to select the first `div` within a specific class then you can use:

```
.class div:first-child
```

This however won't work when you've got the following HTML:

```
<div class="class">
    <h1>The title</h1>
    <div>The CSS won't affect this DIV</div>
</div>
```

It won't work because the `div` isn't the first child of the `.class`. If you wan't to target that `div` in this case I'd suggest adding another container (or adding a class to that `div` whatever you like :) )

Comment: This doesn't technically answer the specifics of the OPs question re: specific IDs. See my suggested answer.

Answer (score 19):

To select the first div in a class I would recommend using this method :

```
.yourClassName > div:first-child{
   // Your properties
}
```

Same if you want to select within an id, just do this :

```
#yourUniqueId > div:first-child{
   // Your properties
}
```

But if you do have an id, your should **ONLY** have one anyway. Otherwise you would be coding ***Invalid*** HTML. Just use a simple selector like this for id's :

```
#yourID{
    // Your Properties
}
```

Also note, that in @sourcecode's answer, he doesn't currently have the `>` in his example. Without this it will not select the first div within a class but will rather select every first div within that class. Check this fiddle out for an example of that :

## [Demo First Selector from each group](http://jsfiddle.net/ConnorM/54gQJ/)

and here is a demo of my answer :

## [Demo First Selector ONLY](http://jsfiddle.net/ConnorM/54gQJ/3/)

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

`.class div:first-child{ your css }`

Comment: I am not going to downvote, but this answer isn't really correct it doesn't select the first div within a class it actually selects the first div of every ground in a class - check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ConnorM/54gQJ/

Answer (score 0):

Just use the id - It should be unique to the page and therefore you know exactly what item you are effecting

Comment: Unless I'm using multiple id's on one page.

Comment: @oceanic815 you know if you have 2 id's the same that's invalid HTML?

Comment: But what if you have the element in different locations on different pages, but you want to style for the pages only where it shows up as the first child in that group?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pseudo classes:

1. :first-child
2. :nth-child(1)

Or you can select by ID:

1. #elementID
2. div[id="elementID"]

The difference between the above two is in specificity; using "#elementID" would have a higher specificity (precedence) than using the attribute selector "div[id="elementID"] but both are correct ways of selecting the element.

Comment: why on earth would you do that? `div[id="elementID"]`

Comment: To explain specificity briefly. Also this is very useful, say when you want to select all ids beginning with or ending with a specific word, for example: div[id^="elem"] (starts with "elem") or div[id$="elem"] (ends with "elem") or div[id*="elem"] (contains "elem").

Comment: You never know, someone else might find it useful :)

Comment: @Connor in case of duplicate IDs (BAD), this can be useful. jQuery when passed only an ID selector (`#\w+`) uses `getElementById`, and finds the first element with that ID. Anything else will force it to use `querySelectorAll` and get all elements with that ID.

Comment: @JanDvorak were on about CSS though

Comment: @Connor it can be useful in CSS if you want to lower the specificity artificially

Comment: @connorspiracist why on earth do you still care about ie6? Do you develop for use in China, because most everywhere else is well under 1% utilization?

Comment: @lampwins you're like 7 months late to the party, therefore you cannot use "still"

Answer (score -1):

Some of the answers don't address the valid scenario where you may have the element in different locations on different pages of your website, but you ONLY want to style for the pages only where it shows up as the first child in that group.

The following solution answers the OP's question on selecting the first element with a specific ID:

```css
.something div{
    background:blue;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    margin:20px;
}

.something div:first-child{
    background:red;
}

.something div#test:first-child{
    background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="something">
    <div id="test">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```