# How to add apply CSS using jQuery's closest method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$("p.ABC ").closest(".b .y").addClass("t");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b">
  <h1 class="y">Hello</h1>
  <div class="a">
    <p class="ABC">A..........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
  </div>
</div>
<div class="b">
  <h1 class="y">Hello</h1>
  <div class="a">
    <p class="BC">A..........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add CSS property only to tag `h1` of first div. How to do it?

Comment: ```$("p.ABC ").closest(".b").find(".y").addClass("t");``` Or just ```$("p.ABC ").closest(".y").addClass("t");```

Comment: @Rayon your second one won't work as `y` is not an ancestor of `p.ABC` - you would need `prevAll` instead of closest

Comment: @Pete - Correct.. I just lost myself as code was not formatted ;)

Comment: You can refer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006763/css-selector-first-div-within-an-id-or-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006763/css-selector-first-div-within-an-id-or-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) will not work with the multi-level selector. Hence, `closest(".b .y")` will not match any element.

You have to use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) on the [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) element:

```js
console.log($("p.ABC ").closest(".b .y").length); // 0

$("p.ABC ").closest(".b").find(".y").addClass("t");
```

```css
.t{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b">
  <h1 class="y">Hello</h1>
  <div class="a">
    <p class="ABC">A..........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
  </div>
</div>
<div class="b">
  <h1 class="y">Hello</h1>
  <div class="a">
    <p class="BC">A..........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
  </div>
</div>
```

Though, I think the easiest way is:

```
$(".b:eq(0) h1.y").addClass("t");
```

Answer (score 1):

The below will highlight the title in the first matching div only

```js
$("p.ABC")            // your starting selector
      .closest(".b")  // get the closest b div
      .first()        // only get the first of these
      .find('.y')     // find the title
      .addClass("t"); // add class to the first div's title only
```

```css
.t {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b">
  <h1 class="y">Hello</h1>
  <div class="a">
    <p class="ABC">A..........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
  </div>
</div>
<div class="b">
  <h1 class="y">Hello</h1>
  <div class="a">
    <p class="ABC">A..........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

$('.b h1:first').addClass("t");

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following:

```js
$("p.ABC ").closest(".a").prev('.y').addClass("t");
```

```css
.t{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b">
  <h1 class="y">Hello</h1>
  <div class="a">
    <p class="ABC">A..........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
  </div>
</div>
<div class="b">
  <h1 class="y">Hello</h1>
  <div class="a">
    <p class="BC">A..........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
  </div>
</div>
```

This line, first gets the parent (closest) of the class `ABC` and then finds the class `y` which is placed before that parent by the `prev` method and then adds a class `t` to it.

Answer (score 0):

`closest()` is to find the parent of the element.

Check this one.

```js
$(".b h1:first").css("color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b">
  <h1 class="y">Hello</h1>
  <div class="a">
    <p class="ABC">A..........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
  </div>
</div>
<div class="b">
  <h1 class="y">Hello</h1>
  <div class="a">
    <p class="BC">A..........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by two ways:

```
1. $("p.ABC").closest("div.b").find("h1.y:first").addClass("t"); // you can add your css on t class.
2. $("p.ABC").closest("div.b").find("h1.y:first").css("color","green");
```

Both will work fine.